# Obtaining DRF-jwt token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

Currently I am generating tokens manually, but I want to to use `jwt` tokens, I followed the official docs and other references but I am still unable to figure out the problem.

**serializers.py**, in which after authenticating token is generated manually.

```
class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    token = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'password',
            'token',
        ]
        extra_kwargs = {"password":
                            {"write_only": True}
                        }

    def validate(self, data):
        username = data.get('username', None)
        password = data.get('password', None)

        try:
            usern = Account.objects.get(username=username)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("User does not exists")

        if usern.check_password(password):
            data["token"] = "asdasdasdasd"
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("password invalid")

        return data
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import AuthRegister, AuthLogin
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^register/$', AuthRegister.as_view()),
    url(r'^login/$', AuthLogin.as_view()),
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
]
```

In settings I have included `'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',`

I have used `url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token)`, but I am unable to figure out how will I generate `jwt` tokens.
Please anyone help me out!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a HTTP POST call to the API on the endpoint `/api-token-auth/`. In this call, the body will contain two keys - `username` and `password`.

**Example using cURL**:

```
curl -X POST -d username=abcd -d password=1234 http://ip:port/api-token-auth/
```